# How to mount external volume for mongoDB using docker-compose and docker-machine

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I would like to persist the `mongoDB` data outside of the container and on a specified volume. I am using docker-compose and the yml file looks like

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python -u app.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/todo
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo:3.0.2
```

Comment: What version? Looks like it might be 2. I'm looking for info on version 3.

Comment: @Dagrooms: were you able to find it? I tried but the data is not persisting on the host

Answer (score 38):

As documented on the docker hub page for that image (https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) you can use

```
volumes:
  - './data:/data/db'
```

Which will use the host path `./data`

Comment: I have this ```web:
  build: .
  command: python -u app.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/todo
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo:3.0.2
  volumes:
    - ./data:/data/db``` but the mongo container does not start and it appears that it is complaining that it does not have write permission on the ./data folder. it says: **2015-12-27T06:55:19.002+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating** im not sure what the problem is

Comment: The problem is the file permissions. Mongo probably runs as the mongo user, which doesn't have the same permissions as your user.

Comment: but the ** /data/db/mongod.lock** is inside the container, not on my host machine. Doesnt this **volumes: - ./data:/data/db* mean the **/data/db** of the container is going to be same as ** ./data ** of the host machine?

Comment: and just in case the problem is with the permission as you stated: "mongo from inside the container not having permission to write on the local disk"; how can i fix this? if this is the case, then what is the standard way of specifying user permissions using the yml file?

Comment: yes, that volume config tells the container to use a host path for the `/data/db` path in the container.  You could move the lock file with a mongo config change maybe, but maybe it is supposed to be in the same path as the data itself.  You can fix the permissions with `chown` or `chmod` on the host. The user id needs to match the mongo user id in the container, or you could give all users `+wx` in the directory.

Comment: I tried `chmod +wx ./data/` on the local folder but still get the same problem. The mongo container does not start

Comment: For future reference, another alternative that can work to make writable is:
volumes:
  - './data:/data/db:rw'

At least that works for named volumes.

Answer (score 11):

I suppose you try to start the container on an OSX system like me? The host machine volume directory cannot be under /Users (or ~) as joshuajabbour points out [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/68).

Try for example

```
 volumes:
   - /usr/local/mongodb:/todo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Mongo Dockerfile
FROM alpine:edge

MAINTAINER "loko" <binario200@gmail.com>

# proxy settings
ARG http_proxy=http://your-corporate-proxy-if-is-need-it/
ARG https_proxy=http://your-corporate-proxy-if-is-need-it/
ARG no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1,15.0.0.0/8,16.0.0.0/8

ADD run /
ADD dosu /sbin/

RUN chmod +x /sbin/dosu && \
  echo http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  apk add --no-cache mongodb

VOLUME /data/db
EXPOSE 27017 28017

ENTRYPOINT [ "/run" ]
CMD [ "mongod" ]
```

## Docker Compose

```
version: '2.0'

volumes:
  data:
    external:
      name: "the-volume-name-you-want"
services:
     web:
       build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
         args:
           - HTTP_PROXY
           - HTTPS_PROXY
           - http_proxy
           - https_proxy
           - no_proxy
           - NO_PROXY
       image: "docker-hub-OR-your-built-image-name"
       environment:
          - http_proxy=$http_proxy
          - https_proxy=$https_proxy
          - no_proxy=$no_proxy
          - HTTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY
          - HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY
          - NO_PROXY=$NO_PROXY
       ports:
         - "8080"
       restart: always
       depends_on:
         - mongo
     mongo:
       image: "your-favorite-mongodb-image-name"
       environment:
          - http_proxy=$http_proxy
          - https_proxy=$https_proxy
          - no_proxy=$no_proxy
          - HTTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY
          - HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY
          - NO_PROXY=$NO_PROXY
       restart: always
       volumes:
         - data:/data/db
```

## build and run

```
docker-compose build .
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your file

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python -u app.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/todo # HERE --> /mnt/c/temp/mongo:/data/db (mnt= root | c = your drive | temp and mongo = folder
  links:
- db
db:
  image: mongo:3.0.2
```

- Then, the value can be /mnt/c/temp/mongo:/data/db

Dont forget to use the environment variables:

```
environment:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: fw324fe
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i'm using docker with windows 10 and using WSL 2 to integrate with ubuntu, i was only able to solve the problem by putting the full path:

```
 volumes:
          - /home/you_user/mongoDocker/docker:/data/db
```

Answer (score 0):

this documentation has helped me:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

To reuse a volume across multiple services, a named volume MUST be declared in the top-level `volumes` key.

This example shows a named volume (db-data) being used by the backend service, and a bind mount defined for a single service.

```
services:
  backend:
    image: awesome/backend
    volumes:
      - type: volume #this is to declare that the type is volume
        source: db-data #this is the name of your already existing volume
        target: /data #this is the target or destination of the data being saved by your volume 
        volume:
          nocopy: true #The nocopy modifier is for when you are creating a volume and data already exists in the container's path, you can specify if you want that data copied when the volume is created.

volumes:
  db-data:
    external: true # the external flag allows you to use volumes created outside the scope of the docker-compose file
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, this the working docker compose `yaml` file  for using docker volume with mongo image :

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mongo-data
        target: /data/db
        volume:
          nocopy: true 
    # environment:
    #   MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    #   MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      # ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      # ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongo:27017/
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).